# simple animation in java script

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to learn Java Script Animations and I found really good examples on this site: *http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#maths-the-function-of-progress-delta*

But the problem is, as a beginner, I don't understand how the functions and objects work with each other.

**Question 01**

I copied the example *"Let’s create a movement animation on it’s base:"* But my version does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .example_path{
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
    }   
    .example_block{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }   
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div onclick="move(this.children[0])" class="example_path">
    <div class="example_block"></div>
</div>

<script>
function move(element, delta, duration) {
  var to = 500

  animate({
    delay: 10,
    duration: duration || 1000, // 1 sec by default
    delta: delta,
    step: function(delta) {
      element.style.left = to*delta + "px"    
    }
  })

}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**output console:** ReferenceError: animate is not defined
Does anyone know what the problem is?

**Question 02**

My second wish is, to integrate the **easeInOut function**

```
function makeEaseInOut(delta) {  
  return function(progress) {
    if (progress < .5)
      return delta(2*progress) / 2
    else
      return (2 - delta(2*(1-progress))) / 2
  }
}

bounceEaseInOut = makeEaseInOut(bounce)
```

How can I link both code snippets? The code is also from this page: http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#maths-the-function-of-progress-delta

Comment: You're missing http://javascript.info/files/tutorial/browser/animation/animate.js

Comment: They define the animate function further up the page you linked, your just missing it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add animate and makeEaseInOut into your script tag then you can use them. You may want to include the functions in a separate JavaScript file eventually.

```
<script>
    function animate(opts) {
        var start = new Date   
        var id = setInterval(function() {
            var timePassed = new Date - start
            var progress = timePassed / opts.duration
            if (progress > 1) progress = 1
                var delta = opts.delta(progress)
                opts.step(delta)
                if (progress == 1) {
                    clearInterval(id)
                }
            }, opts.delay || 10)  
    }

    function makeEaseInOut(delta) {  
        return function(progress) {
            if (progress < .5)
                return delta(2*progress) / 2
            else
                return (2 - delta(2*(1-progress))) / 2
        }
    }

    bounceEaseInOut = makeEaseInOut(bounce)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's what I tried. 
I still have problems. 
**output console:** delta is not a function. bounce is not a function. 
I know I have to learn more about creating functions. But right now I'm not that good to solve the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .example_path{
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
    }   
    .example_block{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }   
</style>

<script>
function move(element, delta, duration) {
  var to = 500;

  animate({
    delay: 10,
    duration: duration || 1000, // 1 sec by default
    delta: delta,
    step: function(delta) {
      element.style.left = to*delta + "px"    
    }
  });

}

function animate(opts) {
        var start = new Date;   
        var id = setInterval(function() {
            var timePassed = new Date - start;
            var progress = timePassed / opts.duration;
            if (progress > 1) progress = 1
                var delta = opts.delta(progress);
                opts.step(delta);
                if (progress == 1) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                }
        }, opts.delay || 10);
}

function makeEaseInOut(delta) {  
    return function(progress) {
        if (progress < .5)
            return delta(2*progress)/2;
        else
            return (2 - delta(2*(1-progress)))/2;
    };
}
varbounceEaseInOut = makeEaseInOut(bounce);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div onclick="move(this.children[0], makeEaseInOut(bounce), 3000)" class="example_path">
    <div class="example_block"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a very simple animation using javascript, hope it helps, try to "Run code snippet" for better understanding.

```js
/*JavaScript*/

function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function Back() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("animate");
  var id1 = setInterval(frame2, 5);
  var pos1 = 350;

  function frame2() {
    if (pos1 == 0) {
      clearInterval(id1);
    } else {
      pos1--;
      elem1.style.top = pos1 + 'px';
      elem1.style.left = pos1 + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*CSS*/

#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
/*HTML*/

<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="Back()"> roll back</button>


<div id ="container">
    <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```